# Is there a dissection tool available online?

Tags: math-software, dissection

I want to write some pages on a website exploring geometric dissections (initially 2d, e.g. Dudeney's, Haberdasher's Problem, Archimedes' Loculus, tangrams and pentominoes, etc., but eventually moving up to 3d: Piet Hein's Soma cubes etc.)

I can spend a lot of time hacking around in e.g. GeoGebra to draw the shapes, but in such an environment I am limited more-or-less to static constructions, and there does not exist the capability to drag, rotate, reflect, pivot around a point, and all that stuff.

There are some fairly sophisticated graphics out there which *must* have been constructed using some sort of tool (unless they have been crafted from raw source code from a graphics package in whatever programming language). But I've done a search and nothing comes to light (and the search results tend also to be clogged with tools allowing visualisations of biological dissections.

Anyone able to help?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[BurrTools](http://burrtools.sourceforge.net/gui-doc/toc.html) offers the ability to construct 3D puzzles with a given set of initial and final shapes, and will search for possible solutions. One can of course make 2D puzzles by creating pieces and targets which are only one layer thick.

The puzzles are fixed to be on a given grid (cubic, triangular prisms, a few other options), so the flexibility is not infinite, but it should cover many of the use cases you have in mind.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I will investigate.